# Ошибка компиляции — «необъявленный идентификатор»

Tags: c++

Вот код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    double f; // Высота
    double m; // Длина
    double h; // Ширина

    cout << "Введите высоту" endl;
        cin >> f; // Высота

        cout << "Введите длину" endl;
        cin >> m; // Длина

        cout << "Введите ширину" endl;
        cin >> h; // Ширина




    sum = f*m*h
    cout << "Это все равно" << sum << "кубометров";

    return 0;
}
```

Где ошибка? Пишет — необъявленный идентификатор, также как и в вызове функции, отсутствует список аргументов.

Comment: `double sum;` - где?

Comment: А еще ошибка в слове "Длина" :)

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь! Извините за мои глупые ошибки и за ваше время потраченное на помощь новичку :)

Comment: Самая первая ошибка - в заголовке: **он ни о чем!** Как по такому можно узнать, какой вопрос обсуждается? Думайте о будущих посетителях.

Answer (score 1):

Код написан ПОЧТИ правильно, но ПОЧТИ не считается =)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    double f; // Высота
    double m; // Длина
    double h; // Ширина
    double sum;//сумма
    cout << "Введите высоту: " << endl;
    cin >> f; // Высота
    cout << "Введите длину: " << endl;
    cin >> m; // Длина
    cout << "Введите ширину: " << endl;
    cin >> h; // Ширина
    sum = f*m*h;
    cout << "Это все равно что " << sum << " кубометров.";
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Перед endl тоже бы не хватало поставить операторы << .
Eg: cout << "Введите длину: " << endl;

Comment: @J.Defenses, `endl` вообще было бы неплохо убрать, ввод может идти и на той же строке =)

Comment: @Даниил Чижевский,  плохая привычка  обявлять локальные переменные  без инициализации

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, с чего бы это?

Comment: @Qwertiy,   Неинициализирующиеся нестатические локальные и регистровые переменные будут иметь неопределенное значение.

Comment: И что? В коде в них дальше происходит считывание. А явно присвоенный мусор ничем не лучше случайного мусора, если алгоритм не предполагал, что инициализация может не произойти.

Answer (score 0):

Укажите тип переменной sum и поставьте оператор вывода перед endl.

Answer (score 0):

Код с исправлением и комментарием об ошибке:

```
#include "stdafx.h"    
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    double sum; // Пропущено объявление суммы с типом дабл 
    double f; // Высота
    double m; // Длинна
    double h; // Ширина
    cout << "Введите высоту" << endl; // Пропущены `<<`
    cin >> f; // Высота
    cout << "Введите длинну" << endl; // Пропущены `<<`
    cin >> m; // Длинна
    cout << "Введите ширину" << endl; // Пропущены `<<`
    cin >> h; // Ширина
    sum = f*m*h;  // Пропущена точка с запятой
    cout << "Это все равно" << sum << "кубометров";
    return 0;
}
```

И не забывайте про табуляцию, всё же код читать будете не только Вы в будущем.

Answer (score 0):

Объяви переменную sum.
Если используешь C++ выше 11. То можно даже так

```
 auto sum = f * m * h
```

Comment: `;` забыли и заводить отдельную переменную только для вывода не обязательно.